# Deploy Github release to Node server with webhooks

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github, webhooks

I've setup a webhook for a repository on Github. When I create a new release in Github, my webhook receiver (on a Node server) receives a request. It works like this (using Express):

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){  

  //request is not a github event
  if (req.headers["x-github-event"] != "release") return;

  //request is a pre-release
  else if (req.body.release.prerelease) deployToDev();

  //request is full release
  else if (!req.body.release.prerelease) deployToLive();

});
```

As you can see, it first checks if the request includes a header of a github event with a value of `release`. If that's all good, it checks whether it's a prerelease or a full release and fires a function to either deploy to dev or live.

The webhook works great, but I'm struggling to find out how to actually deploy the files. Do I do this with some kind of FTP connection or shell script? The dev and live directories are on the same server as the webhook receiver. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using github, a simple way to deploy is by checking out the code on the target machine.

A trade off is that the target machine needs to have git installed and have credentials to read from your repository.

Another option is to do what you suggested in your question: download archive using your node program above and transferring it to the machine you are deploying on using your protocol of choice: FTP/ssh/rsync/scp, etc..

Comment: I'm trying to automate the deployment process based on releases. I think once setup, this will be much quicker and easier going forward. Simply making a new release (prerelease or not) in Github would get it setup and running in the correct area of the server for testing or usage.

Comment: Appreciate your help so far, but I'm no closer to solving this problem. I'm having trouble understanding which actual code to use to achieve my goal. I understand the concepts you've explained already.